# SQL Server 2012 - Deadlock on a Clustered Index Insert

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I have a table whose schema, in part, looks as follows:

[image]

The SubId column is the PK and is a clustered index. I have a C# (using Entity Framework) application that inserts (only inserts) rows into this table. The application is multi-threaded and I normally have four threads running active at one time, inserting rows into this table. Somewhat frequently, I'll get a deadlock that looks as follows:

[image]

I'm really confused by this. Obviously I'm getting a deadlock, but I don't see how. I'm strictly doing inserts and no other process outside my application is accessing this table.

Answer (score 0):

You can get deadlocks even with inserts. For example, assuming you have `CREATE TABLE test23 (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);`

Then

```
--Process 1 :
--1
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO test23(id) VALUES (1);
-- Process 2:
--2
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO test23(id) VALUES (2);


--Process 1 :
--3    
INSERT INTO test23(id) VALUES (2);

-- Process 2:
--4    
INSERT INTO test23(id) VALUES (1);
--Deadlock!
```

Since you didn't provide any details about your table and actual statements, it's really hard to say if that's the case, but I hope it will point you to the right direction.

Comment: It looks like you are achieving this by inserting duplicate values? Process 1 is inserting values 1 and 2. Process 2 is inserting values 2 and 1. That is not happening in my app. I would not have multiple threads attempting to insert duplicate PK values. Each thread is inseting unique PK values.

Comment: @Hosea146: just a guess : it might be due to lock escalation - SQLServer may decide to block the page (just a guess)

Comment: Also, if you use `serializable` isolation level you can get deadlock in the following case :  process 1 : `select from test23 where id = 2; insert into test23 (id) values (1)`, process 2 : `select from test23 where id = 1; insert into test23 (id) values (2)` .